# Using multiple UINavigationControllers for implementing login app

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, login-control, uiwindow

I am working on a navigation based application which involves LOGIN view.
My approach to deal with the same navigation hierarchy (which was taking back to the login page)was

- Use two navigation controllers
- as soon as the user logs in create a new navigation controller

  - assign the new view controller's root to the post login view

    ```
    someViewController.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:someViewController ] autorelease];
    ```
  - assign this navigation controller to the window:

    ```
    MYAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    ```

    appDelegate.navigationController = someViewController.navigationController;

    ```
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [window  addSubview:someViewController.navigationController.view];
    [window  makeKeyAndVisible];
    ```

-finally push the "someViewController" to stack.

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

ALL WORKING FINE TILL NOW..

> outcomes:

1. the someViewController's navigation controller is the new navigationController for the complete app and there is no way to go back to LOGIN view.
2. I am able to push new ViewControllers to the stack and navigate to and fro upto next level.

## PROBLEM :!!

"I am only able to push new ViewControllers to the stack and navigate to and fro. up to the next level and not further..."

say:

(newroot)master-->subordinates--X->details. // i am not able to navigate to 3rd level.
(newRoot)subordinate-->details.

> **what else I have tried before posting?**

1. tried simply setting the root of the same navigationController to the POST-LOGIN ViewControlller

   issue: it din't worked either.

---

**please guide**
**Thank you in anticipation**.

Comment: Where are u writing the code: UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
I mean in app delegate or in view controller?

Comment: @ satyam its on "LoginSuceess" event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way, take a navigationController in appDelegate say `navController` 
In loginViewController, after you login success,

```
HomeViewController *svc=[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

            appdelegate.homeViewController=svc;

            appdelegate.navController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
            appdelegate.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:appdelegate.homeViewController];
            [appdelegate.window addSubview:appdelegate.navController.view];

            [svc release];
```

then you can remove login screen as `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` if added as subView

Comment: I cannot do that because i need one navigationController till login and once logged in, i need to give away this navigationcontroller and get a new one.. this is the soul requirement.

Comment: @geekay You can create a new navigationcontroller and assign it the navController created in window , so that old one will be replaced with new one

Comment: i am doing the same (please see the code) but once I push a view thats OK till then but further(next level) it is not working..

Comment: @greekay but you are fixing navigation controller in a view controller(say someViewcontroller.navigationController), I assigned new navigation controller to the one created globally in appDelegate

Comment: @ SriPriya thanks a lot. I tried all methods all are correct even mine one also the problem was due to really silly mistake done by me yesterday while I was experimenting, I created new properties named "navigationController" which was hiding the global variable and the new view was added to a new stach every time..